# Fortran performance, allocate at each subroutine call or declare a global variable and allocate once

Tags: performance, fortran

I have a subroutine which allocates  four vectors with size = 9, and does some operations on it. These vectors are only used inside this subroutine. The subroutine is called thousands of times during my program run.

Is it worth it to allocate the vectors each time the subroutine is called or it is better to create a global variable and only allocate the vectors once?

Comment: If it is 4 arrays always with size 9 why not just statically size them in the routine? If you don't like that what is wrong with passing them as arguments? Don't use global variables. Just don't. Oh, and it's been spelt Fortran (lower case) officially for 30+ years now.

Comment: First, I agree with Ian.  Use static arrays.  If you want to use allocated array, then give the arrays the `SAVE` attribute and add an `IF` statement to check for the allocation status, e.g., `if (.not. allocated(a)) allocate(a(9))`.

Comment: I'd avoid local saved variables as well - the routine now has internal state which is not good - it's can't be pure and (related) calling it from a threaded code can become painful (depends on details of what you are doing). A routine is a local scope for local variables

Answer (score 2):

For very big working arrays (large 3D arrays) I do declare (global) module variables and then have a clean-up subroutine in the module handy.

However, for vectors of size 9 that really is not necessary. Allocating these on the stack as local variables costs nothing. A local variable of size 9, be it explicit or automatic, costs zero to allocate on the stack. The Fortran standard does not let you decide where the allocation happens but the compilers typically do. And stack tends to be the default.

Static storage is also possible (effectively forced by the `save` attribute) but seems unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables aren't recommended in this case due to two reasons:

1. These variables are only used within the scope of a singular subroutine, setting up a global variable for this purpose is very bad code style.
2. Allocating global variables for specific operations is bad for the expandability of your code.

In this case, a parent subroutine can help: Do not define the vectors within a global scope, but instead, set up a parent subroutine that recieves these vectors as arguments, and let this parent subroutine call the respective (sub-)subroutines. Your vectors are defined within the scope of the parent routine, which means the parent subroutine can pass the vectors to the (sub-)subroutines without needing to access any global references. This would make your code both style-conform and (relatively) more efficient, compared to re-allocating the same vectors every time your subroutine is called.

Comment: A comparison of a "parent subroutine" with local explicit shape arrays (which in most cases will just be put on the stack) may be useful?